# htaccess redirect from subdomain to domain custom 404 page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a domain and subdomain. I created a custom 404 page on the example.com which I can use specifically when the user hits page not found on subdomain.

For example:

When user is on dev.example.com and searches for a page he is seeing example.com homepage as it is a cname for example domain. But when the user searches for a page and receives 404 on subdomain dev.example.com/blah he should be receiving a custom 404 page specifically built for the subdomain and not the domain.com's 404 page. How can I achieve this

Here is what I have written in .htaccess and this doesn't work

```
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.example.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [NC]
  RewriteRule  https://example.com/custom_404 [L,R=301]
```

I haven't used .htaccess to  greater extent and I am exploring, any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can display content from a custom not_found page in subdomain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/custom_404$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /custom_404 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, I am receiving an internal server error after trying this, I have used the custom 404 path in custom_404 path.

Comment: Unfortunately, I wont be able to share the htaccess but I have put this code write below but I have written it write below <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>. what is the better way to debug this

Comment: If you rename this .htaccess to something else, does `http://dev.example.com/custom_404` load fine in browser?

Comment: Yes, it does load when the file is changed

Comment: ok try my updated answer. I am just guessing the problem because I am unable to see all your rules.

Comment: This time I didn't receive any internal service error but i can manually reach the page by typing in the custom redirect path, may be its not picking the custom_404 path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222155/discussion-between-regokonda-and-anubhava).

Comment: Hi Anubhava, Got it to work, it turns out we need a slighly simple rule achieve it.

`  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log-in
  RewriteRule ^ https://test.example.com/custom_404 [NC,L]`

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log-in` means it will show `404` page only for URI `/log-in`. What about all other URIs that can generate 404? Also using `https://` before `custom_404` will do a full redirect and change URL in browser also.

Comment: True, what could be the ideal approach to cover those additional cases

Comment: It is not additional case. I thought problem is: `when the user searches for a page and receives 404 on subdomain dev.example.com/blah he should be receiving a custom 404 page specifically built for the subdomain`

Comment: hmm, yes you are right, that would be ideal, for now I have taken this approach as I need to get this over the line for that particular case until finding the proper redirect solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Got it to work as expected, Thanks to Apache docs and @Anubhav.

 `
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test.example.com
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/log-in
 RewriteRule ^ https://test.example.com/custom_404 [NC,L]
`

 1. Checks if the host is the desired subdomain,
 2. Checks if the REQUEST_URI matches /log-in. One key thing over here is the / as its mandatory for a REQUEST_URI. Using ^ means that the initial part of the string is matched. some working examples ie: /log-in, /log-in/blah, /log-in-anything 
 3. Rewrites and redirects to the custom_404 page
 
References:

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html
```